# Spring Integration Dynamic XML through JAXB or other tool

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-integration

Currently I have a Spring Integration XML file that marshalls Java POJOs to XML using JAXB and then sends them as JMS messages. However, instead of marshalling Java POJOs and sending through JMS I want to send the XML string which will be dynamically generated inside the Java file to JMS in the same integration file below. So I suppose it will probably be done through replacing the existing Marshaller and transformer in the below file for the request but I don't know exactly how.

In short, I would like to know how to send and replace the marshalling of Java POJOs with dynamic XML string.

### Update

I research and Found that DOMSource will be the perfect for generating dynamic XML. I am able to do the transform in Java file from DOM to string easily but I cannot do it through Spring Integration. I need to Marshall from String to XML instead of Java Object to XML using the spring integration file below.

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element root = document.createElement("Root");
        document.appendChild(root);
        Element foo = document.createElement("Foo");
        foo.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bar"));
        root.appendChild(foo);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
         transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), result);
         System.out.println("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());
```

My requirement is to transform the result of the DOMSource to String through Spring integration in the below XML. The change might have to be done in the bean id : Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_MarshallingTransformer below in XML somewhere probably.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Queue names -->
    <util:constant id="Verify_Flight_Detail_SEND_QUEUE"
        static-field="cipac.integration.mq.flight.VerifyFlightDetailGateway.SEND_QUEUE" />
    <util:constant id="Verify_Flight_Detail_RECEIVE_QUEUE"
        static-field="cipac.integration.mq.flight.VerifyFlightDetailGateway.RECEIVE_QUEUE" />

    **<!-- Request Marshaller and Transformer -->
    <bean id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound"
            value="cipac.integration.mq.flight.messages.verifyflightdtl.VerifyFlightDetailReq" />
        <property name="marshallerProperties" ref="MQ_MARSHALLER_PROPERTIES" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_MarshallingTransformer"
        class="cipac.integration.mq.common.marshalling.MarshallingTransformerFactory"
        factory-method="buildMarshallingTransformer">
        <constructor-arg ref="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Marshaller" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="resultToStringTransformer" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>**

    <!-- Reply Marshaller and Transformer -->
    <bean id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound"
            value="cipac.integration.mq.flight.messages.verifyflightdtl.VerifyFlightDetailRply" />
            <property name="marshallerProperties" ref="MQ_MARSHALLER_PROPERTIES" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_UnmarshallingTransformer"
        class="cipac.integration.mq.common.marshalling.UnmarshallingTransformerFactory"
        factory-method="buildUnmarshallingTransformer">
        <constructor-arg ref="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_Marshaller" />
    </bean>


    <int:channel id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:ref bean="cipacOutInterceptor" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Raw">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="request-response-jms-logger" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_Raw">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="request-response-jms-logger" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:ref bean="cipacInInterceptor" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>
    <!-- inbound -->

    <int:gateway service-interface="cipac.integration.mq.flight.VerifyFlightDetailGateway">
        <int:method name="requestReply" request-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req"
            reply-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply" />
    </int:gateway>


    <int:chain id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Chain"
        input-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req"
        output-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Raw" >
    
        <!-- transform -->
        <int:transformer ref="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_MarshallingTransformer" />
    </int:chain>
    
    <!-- outbound -->
    <int-jms:outbound-gateway 
        request-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Raw"
        reply-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_Raw" 
        request-destination-name="#{Verify_Flight_Detail_SEND_QUEUE}"
        reply-destination-name="#{Verify_Flight_Detail_RECEIVE_QUEUE}"
        idle-reply-listener-timeout="${integration.mq.iddleTimeout}" 
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        message-converter="cipacMessageConverter"
        header-mapper="cipacHeaderMapper"
        destination-resolver="cipacDestinationResolver"
        receive-timeout="${integration.mq.receiveTimeout}" 
        time-to-live="${integration.mq.timeToLive}" 
        explicit-qos-enabled="true" 
        delivery-persistent="false"
    />

    <!-- transform -->
    <int:transformer input-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_Raw"
        output-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply" ref="Verify_Flight_Detail_Rply_UnmarshallingTransformer" />
```

That's how the POJO is currently that is getting marshalled.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
public class VerifyFlightDetailReq  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "Flight_Number")
    private String flight_number;

    @XmlElement(name = "PNR_Number")
    private String pnr_number;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Cust_Full_Name")
    private String customerFullName;
```

### Update2:

Please see my answer below that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of struggle i figure out myself. I used DomSource to generate the XML string and then passed it to JMS through the Custom Transformer and not through JaxB Transformer.

**In the Service / Repository class**

```
   VerifyFlightReqID req = VerifyFlightReqID();
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Element root = document.createElement("Root");
            document.appendChild(root);
            Element foo = document.createElement("Foo");
            foo.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bar"));
            root.appendChild(foo);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    req.setXmlPayload(writer.toString());
    verifyFlightDetailGateway.requestreply(req);
```

**In Transformer class**

```
public class DynamicXmlTransformer {
@Transformer
    public  Message<String> buildTransformer(Message message) {
   //Your Data Type which you send through gateway or you can use just use string to pass XML from your service interface
            VerifyFlightReqID req = (VerifyFlightReqID ) message.getPayload();
            
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(req.xmlpayload).build();
}
```

**Spring Inegration XML change**

```
<bean id="DynamicXmlTransformer" class="cipac.integration.mq.common.DynamicXmlTransformer" />
        
        <int:chain id="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Chain"
        input-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req"
        output-channel="Verify_Flight_Detail_Req_Raw" >
    
        <!-- transform -->
        ref="DynamicXmlTransformer" method="buildTransformer"/>
    </int:chain>
```